# How to upload multiple files and view the uploaded files?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I wanted to view the uploaded files. I am uploading 2 PDF's out of which only 1 PDF is showing when I click on uploaded(view) link.
The issue is only `viewing the uploaded file`. I am uploading the 2 PDF files in `agreement folder` where I can see the uploaded files.
But when I click on uploaded(view) link, it displays only 1 PDF file.

https://ibb.co/S3WMmKf\

Below is my code.

Page load:

```
ViewState["filename"] = agremtname;
if (dt.Rows[0]["agreement"].ToString() == "0")
{
    rbno.Checked = true;
    FileUpload1.Enabled = false;
}
else
{
    rbyes.Checked = true;
    lbluploadmsg.Text = "Uploaded(View)";
    agreefile.Attributes["href"] = "~/Agreements/"+ agremtname;             
}
```

Source code:

```
<tr><td class="style11" >Reply recieved date<br/>   <asp:TextBox ID="txtrecdate" Width="207"  class="datepicker" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator10"
            ValidationGroup="valBtoA" ControlToValidate="txtrecdate" runat="server" ForeColor="red" ErrorMessage="reply date!!"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </td>

    <td class="style3">
    Agreement
        <asp:RadioButton ID="rbyes" GroupName="agree"  AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="enablefileuploader" runat="server" />
                  Yes
        <asp:RadioButton ID="rbno" GroupName="agree" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="disablefileuploader"  runat="server" />
                  No&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
           <a id="agreefile" target="_blank" runat="server"><asp:Label ID="lbluploadmsg" ForeColor="blue" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
          </a>
      <br/>    
    </td>
    </tr>

      <tr>


    <td class="style10"> Agreement<br/> 
        <%--<asp:TextBox ID="txtagreement" runat="server" Width="119px"></asp:TextBox>--%>
        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" accept=".pdf,.PDF" AllowMultiple="true" />
       &nbsp;&nbsp; <asp:Label ID="lblfileupmsg" runat="server" ForeColor="red"></asp:Label>
        </td>
    <td class="style12">
    Comment2<br/> 
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtcomment2" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="207" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>       
    </td>
    </tr>
```

Update button code:

```
if (rbyes.Checked)
{
     if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
     {

         agreement = "1";
         filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);
         string fileLocation = Server.MapPath("~/Agreements/" + filename);
         FileUpload1.SaveAs(fileLocation);

     }
     else {
         filename = ViewState["filename"].ToString();
         if (filename == "")
         {
             lblfileupmsg.Text = "Please Upload Agreement file!!!";
             return;
         }
         agreement = "1";
     }

 }
 else if (rbno.Checked)
 {
     filename = "";
     agreement = "0";
 }
```

I know that to view multiple files, I have to use a loop in `page load` but I am not getting how to implement it.

Comment: @fubo my issue is not uploading.The files is getting uploaded.The issue is (viewing the uploaded file) suppose i am uploading 2 pdf file,i can view only 1 uploaded pdf file.

Comment: reopened - I expected the code in the duplicate  mark would solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

You have to take count variable to count the number of files, also you have to save multiple file name in a variable and seperate them using , through logic first.

```
int Count = 0;
```

Inside for each loop

```
     agreement = "1";
     filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);
     string fileLocation = Server.MapPath("~/Agreements/" + filename);
     FileUpload1.SaveAs(fileLocation);
     count++
  if (count > 1)
            {
               string multiplefilename  += "," + filename;
            }
            else if (count == 1)
            {
                string multiplefilename = filename;
            }
```

While Retrieving files to get view

First split the multiplefilename with ,and save the result in array of string and

```
string[] Array = recc.MultipleFile.Split(',');
```

retrieve files then using for loop.